# accessing calendar type as a field value java

Tags: java, eclipse, calendar

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;


public class Station
{
    private Calendar arrival;
    private Calendar departure;
    private int day;
    private String city;

    public Station(String city, Calendar arrival, Calendar departure, int day)
    {
    city = this.city;
    arrival = this.arrival;
    departure = this.departure;
    day = this.day;
    };

    public String getArrival()
    {

    int hr = arrival.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    int mn = arrival.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    String dep = "" + hr + ":" + mn;
    return dep;
    };

    Calendar arto = new GregorianCalendar(2000,1,5,9,30,0);
    Calendar deto = new GregorianCalendar(2000,1,5,16,10,0);
    Station toronto = new Station("Toronto", arto, deto, 5);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    toronto.getArrival();
    };
```

Hello, I'm just starting to learn and I don't understand why this results in a nullPointerException. If I change the method to access the Calendar object directly (arto) then it seems to work fine. Is there something in my Station class that makes this impossible? I'll admit I have limited understanding about the Calendar class. I apologize if the question has been approached before I'm not exactly sure how to ask or find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, in Station() you are using the "this" wrong:

```
public Station(String city, Calendar arrival, Calendar departure, int day)
    {
       this.city = city;
       this.arrival = arrival;
       this.departure = departure;
       this.day = day;
    };
```

"Within an instance method or a constructor, this is a reference to the current object" more info: [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

2nd, you are trying to access a non-static variable "toronto" from a static method "main":

```
static Calendar arto = new GregorianCalendar(2000,1,5,9,30,0);
static Calendar deto = new GregorianCalendar(2000,1,5,16,10,0);
static Station toronto = new Station("Toronto", arto, deto, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's just a simple typo. The constructor should be written like so:

```
public Station(String city, Calendar arrival, Calendar departure, int day)
{
    this.city = city;
    this.arrival = arrival;
    this.departure = departure;
    this.day = day;
};
```

(You were assigning the empty fields `city`, `arrival`, `departure`, and `day` to the parameters.)

Comment: Thank you, it's always something simple that makes me feel stupid for hours hahah.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in constructor of Station class. Look at correct solution

```
package com.stackoverflow.json;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class Station
{
    private Calendar arrival;
    private Calendar departure;
    private int day;
    private String city;

    public Station(String city, Calendar arrival, Calendar departure, int day)
    {
    this.city=city;
    this.arrival=arrival ;
    this.departure=departure ;
    this.day=day;
    };

    public String getArrival()
    {

    int hr = arrival.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    int mn = arrival.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    String dep = "" + hr + ":" + mn;

    return dep;
    };

   static  Calendar arto = new GregorianCalendar(2000,1,5,9,30,0);
    static Calendar deto = new GregorianCalendar(2000,1,5,16,10,0);
    static Station toronto = new Station("Toronto", arto, deto, 5);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    String arrival2 = toronto.getArrival();
    System.out.println(arrival2);
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
9:30
```

Answer (score 0):

This keyword is the reference to the current object.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

You have created your constructor that way wrong, you have added your object to the local variable inside a constructor.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class Station {
    private Calendar arrival;
    private Calendar departure;
    private int day;
    private String city;

    public Station(String city, Calendar arrival, Calendar departure, int day) {
        this.city = city;
        this.arrival = arrival;
        this.departure = departure;
        this.day = day;
    }

    public String getArrival() {
        int hr = arrival.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        int mn = arrival.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        String dep = "" + hr + ":" + mn;
        return dep;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar arto = new GregorianCalendar(2000, 1, 5, 9, 30, 0);
        Calendar deto = new GregorianCalendar(2000, 1, 5, 16, 10, 0);
        Station toronto = new Station("Toronto", arto, deto, 5);
        System.out.println(toronto.getArrival());
    }
}
```

Comment: uggh, thanks for taking the time to answer. I appreciate it.